# Coerce specific column to "double" within a dataframe list

Tags: r, list, dplyr

Let's say I have a list of dataframes

```
 myList <- list(df1 = data.frame(A = as.character(sample(10)), B =
 rep(1:2, 10)), df2 = data.frame(A = as.character(sample(10)), B = rep(1:2, 10)) )
```

I want to coerce column A in each dataframe to double.

I'm trying:

```
myList =  sapply(myList,simplify = FALSE, function(x){  
x$A <- as.double(x$A) })
```

But this returns the coerced values, not even column with column names.

I also tried with dplyr and mutate_if, but with no success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `lapply` with `transform` in `base R`

```
myList2 <- lapply(myList, transform, A = as.double(A))
```

---

Or use `map` with `mutate` from `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
myList2 <- map(myList, ~ .x %>%
                      mutate(A = as.double(A)))
```

---

The issue in the OP's code is that it is not returning the data i.e. 'x'.

```
myList2 <-  sapply(myList, simplify = FALSE,
       function(x){  
               x$A <- as.double(x$A)
               x
            })
```

Comment: I couldn't find the error in my code , thank you for the complete response!

Comment: @GabrielG. There is no error in the code.  It is just that the `return` is not specified.  So, it returns the last assignment instead of the full data 'x'